# "byte" declaration and meaning of %s*%s%s

Tags: c

I have snippet from the C code (for LCD display). The code has no error. I just didn't understand some of snippet codes.

In the code below, lcd_size is declared as byte, but why it can use with normal integer in this code `if(lcd_size >16)` ?

May I know what does "byte" do, when as declaration?

what does `print_str = "%s*%s%s` and `print_str = "%s %s%s"` mean?

```
#define LONGEST 60;    
byte register(char *temp_str,byte lcd_size,byte userlevel, byte unitsplit)
{ 
    char temp_str2[LONGEST];
    char *print_str;  //declares a pointer to a character called "print_str"//
     if (unitsplit) 
        print_str = "%s*%s%s"; //what does this line mean? 

    else {
              if (lcd_size > 16) 
                {
                   print_str = "%s %s%s"; //what does this line mean? 
                 } 
              else 
                 {
                    print_str = "%s%s%s"; //what does this line mean? 
                  }
    }
}
```

Comment: `byte` is a datatype, possibly an alias for `char` or something similar. *"what does print_str = "%s*%s%s and print_str = "%s %s%s" mean?"* It assigns the address of the string to the `char* print_str `. Looks like it's being used for formatted string printing, such as with `printf`.

Comment: I guess you didn't copy the whole function did you ?

Comment: hi Guillaume, yes, i didnt copy the whole function. the code is snipped for the print_str part that i didnt understand .